# JPA Query Pattern Matching

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I have a JPA repository method and the corresponding query

```
@Query(select sc from ScheduleEntry sc where sc.doo ~'[?1]')
```

Schedule findSchedule(String doo);

Doo is the days of operation that consists of the days of week represented as numbers.
eg: If days of operation is monday, wednesday and friday then doo=135

Now I need a query that finds a record that has any one of the given days in the doo.
This query works in postgresql and sc.doo LIKE '%[?1]%' works in sql.
However neither of these are working JPA query. Please help

Comment: The first one is totally invalid JPQL. There is no "~" operator in JPQL. This is not SQL. Read a JPQL reference to see the accepted syntax

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this in JPQL.

```
sc.doo LIKE '%3%' //-- this is true for values - 135, 345, 123 etc. anywhere in the string
```

You can create query & pass parameter.

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT sc FROM ScheduleEntry sc WHERE sc.doo LIKE :dooValue");

query.setParameter("dooValue", "%"+3+"%");
```